# Hibernate works on server but NOT in Eclipse when new entities added

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have looked at countless posts on here and none have seemed to fix my problem. I have an enterprise Java application with `Hibernate` and `JUnit`, but this seems to be more of a test environment problem. Multiple developers are experiencing this issue separately on their local systems in Eclipse. Everything works perfectly fine on a remote `Tomcat` server.

I added **4 new entities** and all are experiencing the same issue so I will focus on 1. I have absolutely ruled out spelling mistakes, not adding the entity to `persistence.xml`, and JPA validation. It validates in `Eclipse` and compiles perfectly, etc.

**NOTES:**

- I have tried both a NAMED QUERY as well as a NATIVE QUERY, and neither work. Native Query throws `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.xx.xx.db.entity.Dog` exception. Named query throws  `org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: Dog.findByDogName`
- We do not use `hibernate-cfg.xml` or something of that nature. We use persistence.xml and my snippet is attached below.
- All of the old entities that were already there (and corresponding
  named queries, annotations, etc) work fine. It's only the new ones
  that are causing problems.
- We are using Eclipse Kepler and Eclipse Juno running on `CentOS 5.9`. Testing framework is JUnit

entity:

```
package com.xx.xx.db.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import com.xx.xx.db.dbenums.*;
import com.xx.xx.db.helper.*;
import com.xx.xx.db.dao.DaoHelper;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOG")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Dog.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Dog a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Dog.findByDogName", query = "SELECT a FROM Dog a WHERE a.dogName = :dogName")
    })


public class Dog implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DOG_ID", length = 16)
private Long dogId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DOG_NAME", length = 16)
private String dogName;

public Dog()
{
    super();
}

public Dog(Long dogId)
{
    this.dogId = dogId;
}
public Dog(Long dogId, String dogName)
{
    this.dogId = dogId;
    this.dogName = dogName;
}

public Long getdogId()
{
    return dogId;
}

public void setdogId(Long dogId)
{
    this.dogId = dogId;
}

public String getdogName()
{
    return dogName;
}

public void setdogName(String dogName)
{
    this.dogName = dogName;
}
}
```

DAO:

```
public Dog findByDogName(String dogName)
{
   try
    {
        dogName = dogName.toUpperCase();
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Dog.findByDogName");
        query.setParameter("dogName", dogName);

        List<Dog> mcList = query.getResultList();
        if (mcList != null && mcList.size() > 0)
        {
            return mcList.get(0);
        }
        _log.debug("dog match not found");
        return null;

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

snippet from persistence.xml:

```
<class>com.xx.xx.db.entity.xxxxxxxxxxx</class>
<class>com.xx.xx.db.entity.xxxxxxxxxxxxx</class>
<class>com.xx.xx.db.entity.Dog</class>
```

Comment: I guess you are using a separate bin directory for running you app locally. If so can you check if the persistence.xml is copied every build (and/or time you change it) to the bin location. Just lost a day on a similar issue with JPA and eclipse Mars (buggy as hell) not copying the persistence.xml file.

Comment: hi! I see that persistence.xml is being built into the target directory of the war, I think this is what you mean? I wonder if there is some kind of 'cache' you can clear for eclipse other than the workspace...? tried that one.

Comment: Usually when you go to **project -> clean** it discards all build information, is that what you mean by clear eclipse cache?

Comment: yeah i'm kinda grappling at straws here. in the past, i've had issues with various frameworks and plugins and just cleared my workspace then re-imported projects and the bugs would be fixed. but i'm not having success with that approach this time. project -> clean doesn't seem to help either :(

Comment: Ok, extremely weird: Work around 1001: use a Tomcat in Eclipse to test with.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our application has multiple persistence.xml files (1 for each sub-project) and even though the "Dog" entity was in the persistence.xml for the sub-projects where the Dogs were being used (and tests were being run), Maven was not able to handle that. It was reading from a persistence.xml first that did not have the Dog entity listed and was unable to merge I guess.

Adding the new entity to all of our persistence.xml files solved the problem, after lots and lots of digging.